# How to delete unused mount points?

Tags: mount, 20.04, mountpoint

How do I delete these 2 unwanted mount points.
[image]

Comment: Unused mountpoints are just empty directories - you can remove them using the `rmdir` command

Comment: @steeldriver I get this `vidath_dissanayake@Latitude-3379:~$ rmdir /mnt/01D60CFF0BF1D440
rmdir: failed to remove '/mnt/01D60CFF0BF1D440': Permission denied
vidath_dissanayake@Latitude-3379:~$ rmdir /mnt/Windows
rmdir: failed to remove '/mnt/Windows': Permission denied
vidath_dissanayake@Latitude-3379:~$  rmdir /media/vidath_dissanayake
rmdir: failed to remove '/media/vidath_dissanayake': Permission denied`

Comment: *"Permission denied"*: you probably need to use `sudo`

Comment: Oops. Ok my bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `sudo rmdir /path/to/mount/point`

Answer (score 3):

Mount points are empty directories. In GNU/Linux, all filesystems are mounted in one tree, and Ubuntu is a GNU/Linux. You tried to remove that directory using `rmdir` command. It's OK. But it said permission denied. It is expected to happen. You are not the owner of neither those directories nor the parent directory, `/mnt` . You must have superuser permissions to remove those. So use `sudo` which give root permissions like this:

```bsh
sudo rmdir /unused/mount/point/
```

It will prompt for the password. Type your password and hit enter. Your password won't be seen, even not dots. That's normal.

Comment: Did not work for me. A mount point is not a directory

Comment: @Juanbuntu A mount point IS a directory .. always. Maybe you didn't type the correct path ? Or the mount point was in use ?

Comment: It could also be the case that the directory which is used as mountpoint is not empty even if nothing is mounted to the directory anymore. This may happen if one tries to save data to the mountpoint while nothing is mounted to the directory. In that case `rmdir` will not work since `rmdir` removes only empty directories and `rm -r` would be necessary.